# What is the best way to design REST URI for nested resources

Tags: rest, nested, uri

Say there are users having multiple authorizations having multiple permissions.

Retrieving all authorizations for the specified user (without permissions) could be:

```
GET users/{id}/authorizations
```

The "normal" case is to *not* embed permissions with authorizations for performance reason.

There are cases when authorizations must be returned with their respective permissions for that user.

Suggested solutions are:

```
GET users/{id}/authorizations/permissions       // does not seem clear
GET users/{id}/authorizations?permissions=true  // with query string
GET users/{id}/authorizationswithpermissions    // new resource
```

Now what is the best way to design the REST URI in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your ideas

> There are cases when authorizations must be returned with their respective permissions for that user.

```
GET users/{id}/authorizations/permissions
```

It is not a good idea to nest collection resource like this. Does it mean "give me all permissions of all authorizations of user `id`"? This is unclear. **Don't do this**.

```
GET users/{id}/authorizations?permissions=true
```

A query is normally used to query, search, or filter on a collection resource. This URL woud return all authorizations for user `id` for which `permissions` is `true`. But what does that man? This is unclear. **Don't do this**.

```
GET users/{id}/authorizationswithpermissions
```

Authorizations are authorizations. Their representation should  not depend on the URI. **Don't do this.**

### Content Negotiation

The solution to your problem is to use content negotiation. You only use *one* URL:

```
GET users/{id}/authorizations
```

This means: Give me a list of all authorizations of user `id`.

Now if you want to  get this list *without* permissions, you could use the HTTP header

```
Accepts: application/vnd.mycompany.authorizations+xml
```

Let's digest this.

- `application`: the first part of the normal MIME type `application/xml`
- `vnd`: a prefix to define your own type
- `mycompany.authorizations`: your type
- `xml`: the second part of `application/xml`

Now if you want to  get this list *with* permissions, you could use the HTTP header

```
Accepts: application/vnd.mycompany.authorizations.permissions+xml
```

Note that me now use `vnd.mycompany.authorizations.permissions`. The server should return the authorizatons *including* the permissions. Only the *representations* are different, not the resources.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal to use an alternative representation of the resource. It suits my need and stays in the spirit of REST.

Comment: To have too many representations can be an overkill. I would go with content negotiation but instead of inventing new representations I recommend to use media type parameters to declare requested granularity. e.g. Accept: application/json;level=1 or application/json;level=permissions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Personnally I can't find any problem with both two last suggestions:

```
GET users/{id}/authorizations?permissions=true  // with query string
GET users/{id}/authorizationswithpermissions    // new resource
```

Except I would change them as follow to be more relevant:

```
GET users/{id}/authorizations?withPermissions=true  // with query string
GET users/{id}/authorizationsANDpermissions    // new resource
```

The first one seems to be quite confusing but your RESTful entities should be documented whatever notation you will opt for.

Comment: Query parameters are normally used to filter or search a collection. So `authorizations?permissions=true` is not recommended.

Comment: Absolutely agree but filtering can be seen as extending results in some cases. Personnaly I will avoid this approach in 99% of cases :)

Comment: 'filtering can be seen as extending results in some cases.' I am unable to imagine any such case.